# Can't get access to room db via onHandleIntent()

Tags: android, service

I'm pretty new to programming and android and try to write one of my first app. I want to reschedule notifications after the phone reboot. I stuck on onHandleIntent() when I trying to get access to db. There is nothing happening and no errors.

**Event.class**

```
@Entity(tableName = "event_table")
public class Event {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "_id")
    Long id;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "event_title")
    private String mEventTitle;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "event_note")
    private String mEventNote;

    
    public Event(@NonNull String eventTitle, String eventNote) {
        this.mEventTitle = eventTitle;
        this.mEventNote = eventNote;
    }

    public String getEventTitle() {
        return this.mEventTitle;
    }

    public String getEventNote() {
        return this.mEventNote;
    }
}
```

**DAO**

```
@Dao
public interface EventDao {
    ...
    @Query("SELECT * FROM event_table")
    List<Event> alarmReschedule();
}
```

**Rescheduler**

```
public class Rescheduler extends BroadcastReceiver {
   
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "publisher onReceive");

        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
            context.startService(i);
        }    
    }
}
```

**MyService**

public class MyService extends IntentService {

```
private static final String TAG = MyService.class.getSimpleName();

    public MyService(){
        super("MyService");
        Log.d(TAG, "constructor");
    }
```

Somthing wrong here I belive (onHandleIntent()).

```
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onHandelIntent");
        EventRoomDatabase db = EventRoomDatabase.getDatabase(this);
        EventDao eventDao = db.eventDao();
        List<Event> notSended = eventDao.alarmReschedule();
        Log.d(TAG, "list size:" + notSended.size());

    //Retern list to other broadcastReceiver for reschedul notificatons
    //reternList(notSended);
    
    }

    @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

   /*reternList(){
    ...
    }*/
}
```

I will really appreciate for any help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

All works fine after changing from this:

```
@Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
```

to that:

```
@Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            super.onStartCommand(intent,flags, started);        
            return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
```